# web application, need to determine if a USB device is connected to the client computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a intranet web application that uses a signature pad to save the signatures of users.  I would like to display the signature control only when the sign pad is connected to the computer.

I have tried query against `Win32_SystemDriver` and `Win32_USBController` using `ManagementObjectCollection` but this will bring the server information.

I declare the control dynamically based on values in a parameter table. So the control is added to the form only if the parameter is needed. Now, if the parameter (signature) is required but the user does not have the signature pad, then I don't want the control to be added in the form.

There are ways to query against the device using the control, but I will have the control displayed in my form... I don't what to display it if not connected.

Comment: Have you googled this? A Quick query returned http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program

Comment: You want a server side control of a web application to query the clietnts usb controller?

Comment: Would you not have to run client side script to see if the signature pad is connected to the client machine?  Not sure if you can do this for security reasons.

Comment: Browsers will hate that - you'll either be looking at a plugin technology (maybe SL or flash), or maybe ActiveX on IE; but really.... Don't. Write a client app, really. Maybe ClickOnce.

Comment: Maybe run a Java or ActiveX control on the client computer?

Comment: @Crunchy that doesn't apply to a web app

Comment: @MikeChristensen: +1 may be the only way.

Comment: @TheMask - I think it's safe to say Javascript doesn't let you enumerate USB devices heh.

Comment: As others have said, trying to access information outside the browser on the clients computer is not possible using standard HTML and the hacks (Flash, ActiveX, etc...) are not be simple to develop.  Why not add a hidden signature control to the page and use JavaScript to hide/show based on the click of a icon/button.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with Flash you could try to get a hold of the USB connection... I don't really think you'll succeed, but it's worth a try.

Otherwise, probably not doable.